# Creating a process that is not child of the process that created it

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork

I want to create a process **B** from process **A**. However, I don't want **B** to be the child of **A**, which will be the case if I simply use *fork*. How can I achieve that? In other words I want process **B** to keep on executing even if process **A** is killed.

Comment: Whose child do you want it to be ?

Comment: cnicutar, Why you removed your answer? I found it quite useful.

Comment: I am glad you found it useful but I think the `setsid` idea is superior :-)

Comment: If B is the child of A, B does continue executing if A is killed.

Comment: One option is to have the child fork again, and the grandchild continues while the child exits (commits suicide).  You still need to separate the (child and) grandchild from the session of the parent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the setsid() function.

Alternatively, as you have tagged your question "linux", maybe you want to use daemon() instead of fork() + setsid().

Comment: Calling setsid does not change the parentage or the process.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think that **B** would not keep executing after **A** is killed if **B** is a child of **A**? That's not true.

But if you still want **B** to not be a child of **A** then you can do this by `fork()`ing twice: once to create a child **A½** and once to create **B**. B is a child of **A½** and a grandchild of **A**. Then have **A½** exit immediately. **B** will be inherited by `init` and will have no further relationship to **A**.

If you are concerned about signals like `SIGHUP` and `SIGINT` that are generated in response to events like a Control-C keypress that are broadcast to the entire foreground process group, see [cnicutar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/714501/cnicutar)'s answer.

Comment: Phew! That is quite complicated :)!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;

    switch(pid = fork()) {
    case -1: 
        perror("fork");  
        exit(1);             

    case 0:
        printf(" CHILD: This is the child process!\n");
        printf(" CHILD: My PID is %d\n", getpid());
        printf(" CHILD: My parent's PID is %d\n", getppid());
        /* you can exec another program here if you wish to */
        printf(" CHILD: I'm outta here!\n");
        break;

    default:
        printf("PARENT: This is the parent process!\n");
        printf("PARENT: My PID is %d\n", getpid());
        printf("PARENT: My child's PID is %d\n", pid);
        printf("PARENT: I'm not going to wait for my child to exit\n");
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
        printf("PARENT: I'm outta here!\n");
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't send the `signal()`, then once after the parents completes the execution (and exits), the child process will be termed as a zombie process. For better understanding, execute the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
Execute this program and do 'ps ax | grep Z' to see that this
is put in a defunct state or zombie state
*/

int main()
{
        pid_t child_pid;

        child_pid = fork();
        if (child_pid > 0) {
                sleep(60);
        } else {
                return 0;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: So basically you mean if parent process exits or is killed, the child will still continue executing? In other words, killing the parent will not kill the child? Any idea what is this subgroup and CTRL+C story?

Comment: @MetallicPriest CTRL+C causes `SIGINT` to be sent to every process in the tty's foreground process group. Using `setsid()` puts the process into a brand new process group (and session) that isn't associated with any controlling tty. That's what makes it a good way to avoid getting the signal. Using `setsid()` is one of the steps toward becoming a daemon process (one of the other steps, for example, being redirecting your own input and output to/from `/dev/null`).

Comment: @MetallicPriest When a child process dies and has not been `wait()`ed on by the parent, it will usually show up in a `ps` listing as `"<defunct>"`. It will remain this way until the parent `wait()`s on it, or it is dealt with `SIGCHLD` signal. OTOH, `SIGINT` is the interrupt signal that a process receives when the user hits `CTRL` + `C`. The default signal handler for SIGINT causes the process to `exit`. But, you can override the `SIGINT` to do whatever you want (or nothing at all!).

Comment: @MetallicPriest [This](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html) link will give you a good introduction to various inter-process communication that is available in Linux. Hope this helps!

Comment: @MetallicPriest If you find the above code snippet help you understand the problem/solution, could you please confirm so by clicking the tick mark next to it?! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I see is having the child orphan (then adopted by init).
This may be achieved by terminating the father process before the child (but just take care of signal propagation).

Some nice samples may be found [here](http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~lwang/fork)